# Freely available Penn-Treebank-like Rewriting Rules corpus?

Tags: english, resource-request, context-free-grammars, treebanks

Hey I'm currently working on my thesis in computer science. For one of my experiments I need a large context-free grammar (set of rewriting rules) that vastly approximates English syntax for some sentence types.

I found that there is a popular corpus called the Penn Treebank Corpus which includes such a context-free grammar. Unfortunately it's not freely available. Do you know where I can obtain such a thing instead?

Thank you very much